# PortfolioAnalytics Error row names not Dates

Tags: r, optimization, portfolio

I am getting the following error from the portfolio analytics package.

```
Error in checkData(R) : 
  The data cannot be converted into a time series.  If you are trying to pass in names from a data object with one column, you should use the form 'data[rows, columns, drop = FALSE]'.  Rownames should have standard date formats, such as '1985-03-15'.
```

The data set I am using is simulated data

```
> df
      X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
 [1,]  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  1  1   0
 [2,]  0  1  0  0  1  1  1  1  1   1
 [3,]  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1   0
 [4,]  1  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  0   1
 [5,]  0  0  1  0  1  0  1  1  1   0
 [6,]  0  1  0  1  0  1  1  0  1   1
 [7,]  1  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1   0
 [8,]  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0   1
 [9,]  1  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1   0
[10,]  0  1  1  0  0  1  0  1  0   0
```

I set the portfolio constraints to be

```
returns = as.matrix(df)
> funds = colnames(df)
> init.portfolio <- portfolio.spec(assets = funds)
> init.portfolio <- add.constraint(portfolio = init.portfolio, type = "full_investment")
> init.portfolio <- add.constraint(portfolio = init.portfolio, type = "long_only")
> minSD.portfolio <- add.objective(portfolio=init.portfolio, 
+                                  type="risk", 
+                                  name="StdDev")
> minSD.opt <- optimize.portfolio(R = df, portfolio = minSD.portfolio, 
+     optimize_method = "ROI", trace = TRUE)
Error in checkData(R) : 
  The data cannot be converted into a time series.  If you are trying to pass in names from a data object with one column, you should use the form 'data[rows, columns, drop = FALSE]'.  Rownames should have standard date formats, such as '1985-03-15'.
```

How can I fix this error.  DF is a simulation of single period returns. So they are all eithe 100% or 0%, and for the same period.  I can add a date variable if I need to as the row names, but I do not know how.  I tried

```
> rownames(df) = as.Date(c("Jan", rep(nrow(df))))
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Can someone help me with this error?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add date data to df.  Assuming that the data is monthly returns beginning at the start of this year, you can either add rownames using

```
rownames(df) <- as.character(seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), length.out=nrow(df), by = "month"))
```

or convert df to an xts time series by

```
library(xts)
df <- xts(df, order.by = seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), 
                                  length.out=nrow(df), by = "month"), df)
```

`xts` is a commonly used format for financial time series and works well with PortfolioAnalytics so you might consider that.

Once you've done that and run optimize.portfolio, you'll won't get an solution.  It appears that df is not positive definite so you'll have to adjust the values in df.

Also I don't quite understand your comment that single period returns require that returns be 0 or 1.  That's not true in general.

Comment: These are simulated betting results, that have a correlations on wins.  I am trying to get a max sharpe ratio (returns/SD) for the bets.  Was struggling with the optimization.  http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/22208/portfolio-optimization-with-equal-weight-for-assets-selected

Comment: The problem seems to be that because of the constraints on the betting results, 'cov(df)' will tend to be singular or almost singular.  The constraints on df include limiting values to 0 or 1, requiring that no two columns be equal, and, apparently, that the number of 0's should be about the same as the number of 1's.  You can try to avoid this by having somewhat more rows than columns.  As an example, if only use columns X2 to X9 by setting `df <- df[,2:9]` , optimize.portfolio should give you a result.  In general, the larger the ratio of  the number of rows to number of columns the better.

Comment: Thanks for this information.  THe larger dataframe has 1000 collumns and 500 rows, so I will make that adjustment

Comment: I don't see how `0` and `1` are proper values for returns.  `1` would mean that your return is equal to your bet so you would double your investment. OK.  However, `0` would mean no return but your investment after the bet would be the same as going in.  In other words, you would never lose money so any strategy will be a winning one.  It would seem that a more applicable set of returns would be `1` and `-1` where `-1` would indicate that you would loose the amount you bet.

Comment: Good point. Ill make that coding change. Thanks for the advice